# Styling InputAlias popup box

Tags: stylesheet

I'm trying to create a dark theme and I'm using the ReverseColor stylesheet as a base. I have most things changed to my liking and fixed some of the problems with ReverseColor. However, I cannot find a way to separately style the pop-up box you get when you do <kbd>Esc</kbd> *name* <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This thing
[image]

It is almost illegible under ReverseColor.

[image]

How do I change the font and background colour of this? The auto-completion popup for functions seems to be unaffected, so it probably inherits its style from something else. Bonus points if you could tell me how to change that also.

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch of issues with the Reverse Color stylesheet.

Comment: Which is why I'm trying to create one fixing as many issues as I can :). For anyone in the future doing the same thing, if you want to fix the usage information you get from `?`,`??`, `Information` etc. you need to adjust the `PrintUsage` and `Info*` styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `"CodeAssistCharCompletion"` style. Add or modify this for your stylesheet:

```
Cell[ StyleData["CodeAssistCharCompletion"]
, FontColor->GrayLevel[0]
]
```

I am not sure you can do anything about background because it looks like a bitmap rather than a plain `Background->color` setting. There's probably something in FEBitmaps directory but it will change global setting of that menu.

Anyway you can find this and related styles in:

*Core.nb / Styles for Mathematica System-specific Elements / Code Assist Styles*

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. I too was digging through Core.nb, but was somehow convinced that it was a _dialogbox_ related style.

Comment: Wow how did you find this trash? (A+) Search for `"CodeAssist*"` in Core.nb and friends?

Comment: @b3m2a1 finding the final section was quite straightforward but first time I approached it I assumed it won't be there. Then I started to change font after font to Red till I hit it.